# ng-class doesn't switch when condition is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my view I do `ng-class="{active:{{name}} == {{her_name}}}"`

I saw in the rendered DOM `ng-class="{active:alice == alice}"` I wonder why it doesn't apply the `active` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **changing**:

```
ng-class="{active:{{name}} == {{her_name}}}
```

**To**

```
ng-class="{'active':name == her_name}
```

`active` is not being assign as a regular `class` because it is a **model** so you need to declare it as a **string** by adding **single quote**.

**Update:**

Using multiple class

```
ng-class="{'active': name == her_name, 'inactive': name != her_name}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you provide the complete code of  the condition you want?

Comment: if name == her_name use class active else use class inactive.